# Coveralls also checks coverage for test classes

Tags: java, maven, coveralls

I have a project (Java) hosted on GitHub and recently I have added both TravisCI and Coveralls for coverage reports. My project is here: [FuzzyImageToolBox](https://github.com/LoreScianatico/FuzzyImageToolBox).
As I can see from my last coverage report [here](https://coveralls.io/builds/4719168) coveralls also shows coverage even for test classes, while I expected that it would show me coverage only for non-test classes. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I did it. My source directory was set to "src", so it included classes for both tests and non-tests objects. Changing in pom.xml file the sourceDirectory to src/main/java did the trick.